# TypeErrpr: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So basically, I'm in an Ionic project, which we succesfully migrated to the 3.0.0 beta version, more or less, two weeks ago. Everything was working properly and I could develop over it without problem.

But this morning, I was using the Ionic 3 beta CLI, and tried to install the ConnectivityService. It couldn't work in that version, so I performed a clean uninstall of ionic, and then, a new install aiming to ionic@latest. It gave a dependency error on app-scripts, so I used the following command:

npm install --save @^1.3.1

Then, I used again "npm install -g ionic@latest". After that, everything stopped working. I can't do anything with ionic anymore; I just keep having the same error with whatever I do: "TypeErrpr: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". It doesn't matter if I uninstall it and install it again; I just can't get it working.

Do you know what might be causing this?

EDIT: This is my package.json file:

```
   {
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.3.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "image-manipulation": "0.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "parse": "^1.9.2",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "0.0.12",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "0.0.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"Do you know what might be causing this?"_ your code? May you edit your question with a [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox While your comment might seem appropiate, it doesn't make sense after all... the code is perfectly fine, nothing changed, but the fact that now I'm getting this error every time I use the ionic CLI tool. Anyways, I'll provide my package.json

Comment: @Zerok "the code is perfectly fine" - first time Ive ever heard of perfectly fine code not working. Can you specify what is triggering the error and include more of the error, or point to where the error is occuring?

Comment: @Zerok so in your `dependencies` you have `"@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.3.1",` but in your `devDependencies` you have `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",`

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks for pointing to that thing. I tried changing it and calling "npm install" again, but it keeps throwing the same error. Anyways, mind that this is an Ionic CLI related issue; not an application code issue. Whenever I call to any of the ionic CLI commands, I get that error. Even writing in cmd "ionic" itself.

Comment: If you think thats the case I would open an issue with Ionic CLI.

Comment: @Craicerjack already done!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Please add the link to your Ionic CLI issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your npm packages are out of date. I would recommend installing [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) and then update your package.json file with 'ncu -u'.